# Psoc Cypress Capsense to Wake Up Sleep Mode

Tags: microcontroller, interrupt, sleep-mode, wakeup

I want to use sleep mode because of the power consumption of the MCU. My aim is basic, but I can not use the process.
I want to use Capsense to wake up my Psoc from sleep mode but ı do not have any idea for this. Is there someone to help me in that case

Answer (score 0):

PSoC has to be awake to receive inputs from CapSense and it is not possible generate an interrupt that can return PSoC from sleep mode. However the device can use the sleep timer to return from sleep mode.

Following method can be used to reduce the current consumption:
Wake up from sleep on sleep timer interrupt >> scan the capsense sensors >> go to sleep again
To reduce the power consumption even further, instead of scanning all the sensors, there is a gang sensor feature in capsense which connects all sensors internally making it a large sensor and can be scanned such that the active time (time required to scan all sensors) is reduced. If there is a touch detected in the ganged sensor, individual sensors can be further scanned again to determine the which sensor was touched.